# Text reading experience in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, text, uiwebview

I want to implement a great text reading experience in my app, similar to "Pocket", that would look a lot like this:

[image]

Basically, I'd like to have control over the text font size and font family while loading local HTML files in a UIWebView.

Could anyone point me to the right direction? Are there any frameworks or libraries out there that provide the base for such experience?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer is: don't. Instead load it into a UITextView. You can easily change the font size with it, as on HTML you would have to modify the file instead of calling 1 line of code.